# filling listView when button clicked in other activity

Tags: java, android

Is there a way how you can add a string to an arraylist, which then fills a listview when a button is clicked in another activity? To be more clear: In activity A, I have a Listview and a menu item where I can go to Activty B. In Activtiy B I have got an EditText and a button. I want to achieve that everytime I click on the Button in activty B, the new String gets listed in the Listview. As a "clicklistener" I used a boolean. Is there a better way? Because with the code below I can only make one list entry which gets changed by every next button click.

Java Code Activity A:`package com.example.schoolapp;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvSubjects;
ListView listView;
static ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvSubjects = findViewById(R.id.tv_subjects);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
arrayList);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    if (NewNoteActivity.buttonClicked){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String string = intent.getStringExtra("Subject");
        arrayList.add(string);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

//Code for the menu, works fine

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.item_newSubject:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewNoteActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
}`
```

Java Code for Activity B:
public class NewNoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText et_subject;
Button btn_createSubject;
String subject;
static boolean buttonClicked = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_note);

    et_subject = findViewById(R.id.et_subject);

    btn_createSubject = findViewById(R.id.btn_createSubject);
    btn_createSubject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonClicked = true;

            subject = et_subject.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Subject", subject);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    buttonClicked = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Use [SharedPreferences](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) to store a list of the subjects and access the subjects in the other class.

Comment: Please refer to the link: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#custom

Comment: What you want is referred to as an "Activity result". Basically, this is where you start in `Activity` A and make a call to open `Activity` B, but with the promise that you'll get a result back upon returning to `Activity` A. This is what @MojoJojo has linked above. There's also an older (and arguably less confusing) way to do it, which involves calling `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: Could you give me a code example because I really don't know how that could solve my problem...